# How to declare a PHP class constant with concatenation?

Tags: php, class, constants

In a PHP5 class I want to declare a constant as follows:

```
class MyClass
{
    const sEOLChars = chr(13) . chr(10);
```

which produces an error (`Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '(', expecting ',' or ';'`).  How to do it right?

Comment: The problem isn't the concatenation, rather the function call to `chr` - with your specific error, you still can't concatenate in `const`.  But `const sEOLChars = '\n\r';` would be, I believe, equivalent to what you are trying to do.

Comment: Ah I see. I was not sure of the exact cause of the problem. Your suggestion seem to work.

Comment: I may have mixed up the order, may be `'\r\n'` for the actual order of those you were using - if the order matters when using the `const` for you, just a heads up. ^^

Comment: Don't forget there's already a built-in PHP_EOL constant for the end-of-line character or sequence

Comment: As mentioned [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15963172/constants-var-inside-a-class-class) and [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6500732/public-static-variable-value) there is no possibility in current PHP to assign evaluation expressions to class fields / consts within it's declaration.

Comment: @CORRUPT based on the question title, I don't believe they were trying to assign a non-scalar value, but rather thinking it was the concatenation that failed. Probably without really realizing that `chr(13)` was technically a function call to get the value for it.  I mention all that as I don't think it is a duplicate of either of your links.

Comment: @Jon I don't considered this question as a dublicate too. Just provided other links. With respect.

Comment: @CORRUPT point taken ^^ Most of the time when SO links are posted a duplicate flag is close behind - just wanted to give my opinion of why it shouldn't be flagged as such just in case. =]

Comment: @Jon Shouldn't it be `"\n\r"` instead? (Double quotes instead of single quotes)

Comment: @JeromeJ Erm, yes. Hadn't noticed I used `'` before, good catch.

Comment: While not directly applicable for the exact scenario shown here, note that real constant expressions were added in PHP version 5.6, as per this RFC: http://wiki.php.net/rfc/const_scalar_exprs

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I figured I'd post my solution as an answer - just in case no duplicate for the question is found.

For your specific error, the problem is the function call to [`chr`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.chr.php).  Though, to answer the title, concatenation is not currently possible for class `const`'s.

To solve your particular issue though, you can make use of the back-reference's of `\r\n` making your line look like:

```
const sEOLChars = "\r\n";
```

OR you can use the built-in [`PHP_EOL`](http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.constants.php) constant, but be advised it only gives you the end of line constant for your current platform. ^^

Answer (score 3):

`chr(13)` is equivalent to `"\r"` (CARRIAGE RETURN) and `chr(10)` is equivalent to `"\n"` (LINE FEED). So basically you can write your code like this:

```
class MyClass
{
    const sEOLChars = "\r\n";
}
```